How to send a file as string to Spring Boot multipart rest api
I have a spring boot controller with
@RestController
@Tags(@Tag(name = "app"))
public class MyController {

    @Operation(
        requestBody = @RequestBody(
            content = @Content(
                mediaType = "multipart/form-data",
                schema = @Schema(type = "object"),
                schemaProperties = {
                    @SchemaProperty(name = "info", schema = @Schema(implementation = Info.class)),
                    @SchemaProperty(name = "file", schema = @Schema(type = "string", format = "binary"))
                }
            )
        )
    )
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload")
    ResponseEntity<Void> upload(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        byte[] file = request.getPart("file").getInputStream().readAllBytes();
        System.out.printf("=================== %s ===========================%n", uuid);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(file).substring(0, 2750));
        Path path = Paths.get(".\\file_" + uuid + ".pdf");
        try { Files.write(path, file);}
        catch (IOException exception) { throw new RuntimeException(exception); }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
    
}

From that controller I generate 2 open api files.
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: OpenAPI definition
  version: v0
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:8080
    description: Generated server url
paths:
  /upload:
    post:
      tags:
        - app
      operationId: upload
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                info:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Info'
                file:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
  /test:
    get:
      tags:
        - app
      operationId: test
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
components:
  schemas:
    Info:
      type: object
      properties:
        firstname:
          type: string
        lastname:
          type: string

And the second with a little change, I remove the format: binary
                file:
                  type: string

Then, with the openapi-generator-maven-plugin I generate 2 clients.
For the first definition file, the plugin generates a method with that signature
public void upload(Info info, File _file)

And for the second
public void upload(Info info, String _file)

I test all that with
File originalPdf;
try { originalPdf = new ClassPathResource("Original.pdf").getFile(); }
catch (IOException exception) { throw new RuntimeException(exception); }
try { appApi.upload(new Info(), originalPdf); }
catch (ApiException exception) { throw new RuntimeException(exception); }

byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int) originalPdf.length()];
try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(originalPdf)) { inputStream.read(byteArray);}
catch (Exception exception) { throw new RuntimeException(exception); }
try { appApiString.upload(new Info(), new String(byteArray)); }
catch (ApiException exception) { throw new RuntimeException(exception); }

The original pdf contains (just the begining)
00000000:  2550 4446 2d31 2e37 0d0a 25b5 b5b5 b50d 0a31 2030 206f 626a  :%PDF-1.7..%......1 0 obj
00000018:  0d0a 3c3c 2f54 7970 652f 4361 7461 6c6f 672f 5061 6765 7320  :..<</Type/Catalog/Pages 
00000030:  3220 3020 522f 4c61 6e67 2866 722d 4245 2920 2f53 7472 7563  :2 0 R/Lang(fr-BE) /Struc
00000048:  7454 7265 6552 6f6f 7420 3136 2030 2052 2f4d 6172 6b49 6e66  :tTreeRoot 16 0 R/MarkInf
00000060:  6f3c 3c2f 4d61 726b 6564 2074 7275 653e 3e2f 4d65 7461 6461  :o<</Marked true>>/Metada
00000078:  7461 2034 3120 3020 522f 5669 6577 6572 5072 6566 6572 656e  :ta 41 0 R/ViewerPreferen
00000090:  6365 7320 3432 2030 2052 3e3e 0d0a 656e 646f 626a 0d0a 3220  :ces 42 0 R>>..endobj..2 
000000a8:  3020 6f62 6a0d 0a3c 3c2f 5479 7065 2f50 6167 6573 2f43 6f75  :0 obj..<</Type/Pages/Cou
000000c0:  6e74 2031 2f4b 6964 735b 2033 2030 2052 5d20 3e3e 0d0a 656e  :nt 1/Kids[ 3 0 R] >>..en
000000d8:  646f 626a 0d0a 3320 3020 6f62 6a0d 0a3c 3c2f 5479 7065 2f50  :dobj..3 0 obj..<</Type/P
000000f0:  6167 652f 5061 7265 6e74 2032 2030 2052 2f52 6573 6f75 7263  :age/Parent 2 0 R/Resourc
00000108:  6573 3c3c 2f46 6f6e 743c 3c2f 4631 2035 2030 2052 3e3e 2f45  :es<</Font<</F1 5 0 R>>/E
00000120:  7874 4753 7461 7465 3c3c 2f47 5337 2037 2030 2052 2f47 5338  :xtGState<</GS7 7 0 R/GS8
00000138:  2038 2030 2052 3e3e 2f58 4f62 6a65 6374 3c3c 2f49 6d61 6765  : 8 0 R>>/XObject<</Image
00000150:  3131 2031 3120 3020 522f 496d 6167 6531 3320 3133 2030 2052  :11 11 0 R/Image13 13 0 R
00000168:  3e3e 2f50 726f 6353 6574 5b2f 5044 462f 5465 7874 2f49 6d61  :>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/Ima
00000180:  6765 422f 496d 6167 6543 2f49 6d61 6765 495d 203e 3e2f 416e  :geB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/An
00000198:  6e6f 7473 5b20 3920 3020 5220 3130 2030 2052 5d20 2f4d 6564  :nots[ 9 0 R 10 0 R] /Med
000001b0:  6961 426f 785b 2030 2030 2035 3935 2e33 3220 3834 312e 3932  :iaBox[ 0 0 595.32 841.92
000001c8:  5d20 2f43 6f6e 7465 6e74 7320 3420 3020 522f 4772 6f75 703c  :] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<
000001e0:  3c2f 5479 7065 2f47 726f 7570 2f53 2f54 7261 6e73 7061 7265  :</Type/Group/S/Transpare
000001f8:  6e63 792f 4353 2f44 6576 6963 6552 4742 3e3e 2f54 6162 732f  :ncy/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/
00000210:  532f 5374 7275 6374 5061 7265 6e74 7320 303e 3e0d 0a65 6e64  :S/StructParents 0>>..end
00000228:  6f62 6a0d 0a34 2030 206f 626a 0d0a 3c3c 2f46 696c 7465 722f  :obj..4 0 obj..<</Filter/
00000240:  466c 6174 6544 6563 6f64 652f 4c65 6e67 7468 2034 3230 3e3e  :FlateDecode/Length 420>>
00000258:  0d0a 7374 7265 616d 0d0a 789c ad95 d16b 1431 10c6 df17 f67f  :..stream..x....k.1......

On the last line starting at the e of stream it gives 616d 0d0a 789c ad95 so 114, 101, 97, 109, 13, 10, 120, -100
Now looking at the results of the upload api.
With the pdf as File, the same bytes sequence is 114, 101, 97, 109, 13, 10, 120, -100  And it is ok.
With the pdf as String, the sequence is 114, 101, 97, 109, 13, 10, 120, -17
What could make such a difference ?  Is it a encoding problem ?
I tried adding utf-8 or cp1252 for the new String(byteArray).  For each the sequence (-100) is different but none is right.
And looking at the client log, for the first try (File)
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Original.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 51375

and for the second (String)
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 87293

The length is the same as original for the first and much larger for the second.
What can I do ?

What is your real problem? Its the open API or your Controller? And what is your expected output? Why not ResponseEntity<Void> upload(MultipartFile file) instead of ResponseEntity<Void> upload(HttpServletRequest request)?

The endpoint is not mine.  Here it is only to simulate it.  It's written like that and cannot be change.  I simply expect that the pdf I send is correctly received and can be written to exactly the same file.

I pasted code in new project and tested with a random pdf (16MB) and got readable new pdf in server, I sent with postman, Content-Type is multipart/form-data.
